# plotting an inverse function with R

Tags: r, function, inverse

So i have a function defined conditionally as shown in the following R code, and it's integration between -1 and t.

```
f <- function(x) ifelse((x<=1 & x>=-1),3/4*(1-x^2),0)
F <- function(t) integrate(Vectorize(f),-1,t)$value
```

By using:

```
plot(Vectorize(F),-2,2);
```

i get the curve of F.

Now i want to plot the inverse function of F, so after doing some research i found the uniroot function and tried to use it this way:

```
Finv <- function(s) uniroot(function(t) F(t) - s, lower=-1,upper=1)
```

to solve the function F(x)=y in [-1,1].
But when trying to plot the result:

```
 plot(Vectorize(Finv),-2,2)
```

i keep getting the following error :

```
Error in uniroot(function(t) F(t) - s, lower = -1, upper = 1) : 
        f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

i can't understand what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

For x in [-1,1]  F takes on values from 0 to 1. Therefore, Finv is only defined on [0,1].  You cannot plot it [-2,2]. If you restrict your plot to the appropriate domain,  it will work fine.

```
plot(Vectorize(Finv),0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget the $root at the end of uniroot to get the specific value:

```
Finv <- function(s) uniroot(function(t) F(t) - s, lower=-1,upper=1)$root
```

So it should look (and work) like this:

```
f <- function(x) ifelse((x<=1 & x>=-1),3/4*(1-x^2),0)
F <- function(t) integrate(Vectorize(f),-1,t)$value

Finv <- function(s) uniroot(function(t) F(t) - s, lower=-1,upper=1)$root

plot(Vectorize(Finv),0,1)
```